# when does an Angular2 app run

Tags: angular, asynchronous

My scenario is as follows

- I loading a script using async
- Angular app is using some code injected from this script

My question around this is

- When does an actual angular app run, is it after loading the async script?
- If not then how do I get the angular app to execute some code after the async script is loaded?

Comment: That depends on how your index.html looks like.

Comment: Simply put, this what my index.html looks like
<body>
  <script src='script' async></script>

  <app>Angular App Loading...</app>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

In the Angular app I need to make use of a variable loaded by the async script.

Comment: What's the point of loading it async if the following script depends on it?